# How to exclude personal traffic without IP in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

How to exclude my personal traffic from Google Analytics without IP? I am working on site regularly from many browser's but on one computer and just from home.

Comment: We would have to know more. Are you doing this at home or work for example?? Are you doing this when you are out such as from the local coffee shop hotspot?? Otherwise, there is not way for us to answer this.

Comment: Just only from home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realyze that Ghostery is my solution.

Answer (score 2):

1. To completely disable data tracking, you can add an opt-out function to your site:

   https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#optout

   You could also use the Opt-out browser plug-in (available for multiple browsers):
   https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout
2. Set-up a custom dimension to exclude traffic

   Create a custom dimension, call it "Internal traffic" (or anything you wish). Make it "User"-level to make it persist across visits. If your browser automatically clears cookies, you'll still have to revisit the page each time you open it.

   Create a filter to exclude traffic when that dimension (ie: Dimension1) is set to the value (ie: "Internal traffic").

   Set-up a page on your domain that you can visit that sets this custom dimension in your browser. It will stay as long as your cookies are not cleared.

   ```
   ga('send', 'pageview', {
       'dimension1':  'Internal traffic'
   });
   ```

   Help on custom dimensions: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets

Answer (score 0):

Your telco should be using a sub-domain that identifies you in a manner of speaking. It will change each time you connect your cable, dsl, or heaven forbid- dial-up. Each time, you will get an IP address that is tied to a sub-domain name by your carrier. You can get this by accessing something on your website and checking your log file. You may have to wait for the log file cache to write though. Do something unique so you know it is you. Then you can simply exclude that domain name from your reports. It will not be perfect, but close enough.